# Hiding children depending on their IDs in Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

As you can see below, I have a list of items.

My goal is to hide all children of `id="parent"` that has an id >= (greater than or equal to) 6.

How can I achieve this effect using jQuery?

```
<ul id="parent">
   <li id="1"></li>
   <li id="2"></li>
   <li id="3"></li>
   <li id="4"></li>
   <li id="5"></li>
   <li id="6"></li>
   <li id="7"></li>
   <li id="8"></li>
   <li id="9"></li>
   <li id="10"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Although legal in HTML5, I wouldn't advise using numbers as ID's

Comment: @Zenith nor me but infact, i don't know why...

Comment: @roasted Because it's legal in HTML5, but not in CSS. So `<p id="1">Hi!</p>` is legal, but `#1 { color: red; }` isn't and won't work (there's probably work arounds but I can't remember them right now)

Comment: @Zenith so now i know why! :)

Comment: @Zenith There's a workaround but it's ugly (and I don't even know if it's optimized) : `[id="1"]`. It's better to simply avoid those id.

Comment: @dystroy: you could also use unicode escapes (albeit it's definitely no prettier).

Comment: @DavidThomas didn't think about this one... does it work ? in all browsers ?

Comment: @dystroy: I can confirm that it works in Chrome 27 and Firefox (19 and 21) on Win XP. As to other browsers (IE on *this* machine won't play with JS Fiddle), I'm unable to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use filter where the filter function returns a comparison on the id.

```
$('#parent > li').filter(function(){
    var id = this.id || "0";
    return parseInt(id, 10) >= 6;
}).hide();
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/dQ2N2/

Comment: @dystroy - I know, but I prefer to be more explicit rather than use automatic type conversions in these type of cases.

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest using simple CSS for this, rather than JavaScript:

```
#parent li {
    display: none;
}

#6,
#6 ~ li {
    display: list-item;
}
```

I forgot that, while in theory the above works (in that an HTML `id` can start with a numeric character) a CSS identifier can't start with a numeric character, *but it can* if you use a unicode escape, to give:

```
#parent li {
    display: none;
}

#\35 ~ li {
    display: list-item;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/eMFhP/1/).

It occurred to me (a little later than might have been useful) that if your `id`s increment by one and they're a numbered list, you could simply use `:nth-child()` notation:

```
#parent li {
    display: none;
}

#parent li:nth-child(5) ~ li {
    display: list-item;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/eMFhP/2/).

Answer (score 3):

You can use [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/), after having used an attribute selector matching only the elements having an id :

```
$('[id]').filter(function(){return this.id>=6}).hide();
```

You probably already know that an id can be given to only one element, that's why I didn't test that elements are in #parent, but you may if you wish :

```
$('#parent [id]').filter(function(){return this.id>=6}).hide();
```

Comment: @jfriend00 [what do you mean](http://jsbin.com/usajob/2/edit) (click "run with JS") ?

Comment: @dystroy.. u need to use `parseInt`

Comment: @Sushanth-- No, the string is converted to a number in the comparison, no need to convert. And check the link, it works...

Comment: It just works and actually answering the OP question. But i suspect OP doesn't know what i was asking

Comment: @dystroy - you didn't have the `return` in there when I tried it.  Also, the OP asked for children of `id="parent"` which your code doesn't do.

Comment: Sure he had as im aware of

Comment: @jfriend00: technically, yours doesn't return children either... it returns descendants.

Comment: Did the downvoter actually try this out before making their decision?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#parent').find('li:gt(6)').hide()
```

Comment: i though it was a good answer but actually OP want to filter by id, not index

Comment: @user2310422 you should rewrite your question then as here, it's not filtering by id

Comment: OP, do you realize this doesn't test the id but just the index of elements ?